# How would you define a geodesic in $\operatorname{SO}(2n)$ and $\operatorname{SO}(2n+1)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider me a beginner. I am trying to find the intrinsic diameter of $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ and $\operatorname{SO}(2n+1)$, but I am unsure how to define a metric between two different points in either of these spaces. When I asked my professor about the metric he gave me the answer "Distance along shortest path in $\operatorname{SO}(n)$, which sits in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$".

From what I understand, $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ is the group of $n\times n$ orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$. They can be parametrized as rotation matrices, so you can look at them as points on an $S^{n-1}$ sphere, I think. Would I define my path to be the path between points on these spheres?

Comment: $\text{SO}(n)$ is not homeomorphic to a sphere for $n \ge 3$. I think your professor wants you to put the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ (but you really should ask because this question is unclear). More intrinsically you can consider the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product $\text{tr}(A^{\dagger} B)$ which induces the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ (and this induces a different intrinsic metric on $\text{SO}(n)$).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan could you describe the *induced intrinsic metric*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in your interpretation, but incorrect with regards to the spheres. Think about $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. The distance between two matrices $A, B \in \mathrm{SO}(n)$ will be the shortest length of a path $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ that connects $A$ and $B$, so $\gamma(0) = A$ and $\gamma(1) = B$, which passes **only** through elements of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. That is, $\gamma(t) \in \mathrm{SO}(n)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, the path is through orthogonal matrices.

Like Qiaochu said above, $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ is not a topological sphere if $n > 2$, but even if it was, if you work with your definition of the distance, it wouldn't help you much. For example, even though $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is homeomorphic to a circle through
$$ \theta \mapsto \left( \begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right) \mapsto (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta), -\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta)), $$
you need to think about it as sitting in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and minimize the distance in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to all paths that pass through $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Alternatively, if you are familiar with Riemannian metrics, you can work infinitesimally and pull everything back to your preferred description using any coordinates you want.

---

To expand on my last point, I'll demonstrate it for $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Let us denote the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^4$ by $(x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4)$ and we will identify the circle $S^1$ with $[0,2\pi]$ with ends point identified. Consider the map $ \varphi : [0, 2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}^4$ given by $\varphi(\theta) = (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta), -\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta))$. This map gives a diffeomorphism between $S^1$ and $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ inside $\mathbb{R}^4$. But from the existence of this map, you cannot conclude that the image, geometrically, looks like a circle. A priori, the image might look like a very complicated loop which doesn't resemble geometrically circle at all, something like:
[image]

If that is the case, the fact that you have a map from the nice circle to $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ wouldn't a priori help you at all to answer questions such as what is the diameter of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$.

How can you understand the geometry of the image? You can pull back the standard Riemannian metric to $S^1$ and think about it as a one-dimensional **Riemannian** manifold $(S^1, g)$. All the metric properties of $\mathrm{SO}(2) \subset \mathbb{R}^4$, as a metric space with the metric induced from the metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$, and much more, can be then deduced from the one-dimensional Riemmanian manifold $(S^1, g)$. You can forget about the embedding!

The standard Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is given by $\sum_{i=1}^4 dx^i \otimes dx^i$. We have
$$ x_1 = \cos(\theta), x_2 = \sin(\theta), x_3 = -\sin(\theta), x_4 = \cos(\theta). $$
Taking the differentials, we have
$$ dx_1 = -\sin(\theta) d\theta, dx_2 = \cos(\theta) d\theta, dx_3 = -\cos(\theta) d\theta, dx_4 = -\sin(\theta). $$
So the pullback of the metric is just
$$ g = (-\sin(\theta) d\theta) \otimes (-\sin(\theta) d\theta) + (\cos(\theta) d\theta) \otimes  (\cos(\theta) d\theta) +  (-\cos(\theta) d\theta) \otimes  (-\cos(\theta) d\theta) + (-\sin(\theta) d\theta) \otimes (-\sin(\theta) d\theta) = 2 d\theta \otimes d\theta. $$
This means that as a Riemannian manifold, $(S^1,g)$ looks exactly like the circle of radius $r = \sqrt{2}$. In particular, the length of the loop $\mathrm{SO}(2) \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is $2\sqrt{2}\pi$ and the diameter of this metric space is $d = 2\sqrt{2}$.

So in fact, the image doesn't look as a complicated loop but "similar" to the good old circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$. If it would look like a complicated loop, the pullback metric wouldn't be as nice but would look like $g = f(\theta) d\theta \otimes d\theta$ for some non-constant function $f(\theta)$, and still, you could deduce from the model $(S^1,g)$ all the information you want about $\mathrm{SO}(2) \subset \mathbb{R}^4$.

In this simple example, you can of course see it directly, as the image is
$$ \{ \cos(\theta)(1, 0, 0, 1) + \sin(\theta)(0, 1, -1, 0) \}. $$
The vectors $(1,0,0,1)$ and $(0,1,-1,0)$ are orthogonal, and of length $\sqrt{2}$, so you get the result immediately, but the idea of the Riemannian approach is to forget about the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and encode everything in the (pullback) metric, working with $(\mathrm{SO}(n), g)$, a Riemannian manifold of dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. For example, $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^3$. If you compute the pullback metric, you might discover that it looks like a familiar metric on $\mathbb{RP}^3$ and then deduce the metric properties from those of $(\mathbb{RP}^3, g)$.

Comment: +1 nice. Could you explain your last sentence a little further?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In $R^{n^2}$, do we compute the Euclidean distance as if the matrix was a long vector, adding up the squares of the components and taking a square root?

Comment: draks, I've added a further explanation, but one should be familiar with Riemannian metrics to fully appreciate it. Mike, yes.